# Simplified endurance training

Tags: exercise-technique, endurance

I have been getting fit an healthy the last couple of months. I have been toying with the idea of doing 10 reps x 5 exercises (set) as many times in a given session as I can. My thinking here is that I should see an increase in sets over time as my endurance increases.

My question is, assuming I am doing my exercises correctly, does this sort of endurance training have any long term negative effects?

My reasoning for doing this is that I find I stick to exercising more when I don't try to over track it. By following the routine above I can just go until I cannot complete a full set. At this stage I cool down and stop, regardless of the number.

Comment: What kind of long term negative effect? Injuries? Weakness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing particularly wrong with what you're planning to do, but the normal when working for endurance would be 3 sets of 12-20.  Then, when you can complete the 3 sets, you increase the weight and go back to 2 sets.  You would only really do so many sets if you were training for strength/power, heavy weight, few reps but lots of sets.

Like Kneel-before-ZOD says, I can't think of any long term negative affects